# Gridview datasource is null after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a page with a gridview that show article groups,and textbox and search button for search groups.
in this page if user not search anything ,grid view only show main groups(with parentId 0)
and else show every group that group name's contain textbox value.
My problem is when I search ,and then I want to update some row,GridView1_RowUpdating not fired...
I found that the problem is that gridview datasource not bound successfully.
how I fix this problem?
below is my source:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="txt" Text="searchgroups " ForeColor="#68a2d7"></asp:Label>

                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="txt" Text="group name" ForeColor="#68a2d7"></asp:Label>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" CssClass="txt" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

           <br/>

                    <asp:ImageButton ID="Ibtnsearch" runat="server" ImageAlign="Left" ImageUrl="../Icon/resize/search.gif"
                        OnClick="Ibtnsearch_Click" />
                <br/>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" CssClass="txt" AllowPaging="True"
                        OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
                        OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
                        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand1" PageSize="15" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting">
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <Columns>

                            <asp:BoundField DataField="chid" SortExpression="chid" HeaderText="ID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="chname" SortExpression="chname" HeaderText="Name" />


                            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="chid,cLanguage" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../default.aspx?pnl=lstcatChat&amp;nParentid_fk={0}&lang={1}"
                                Text="Sub Groups" HeaderText="Show Sub Grups">
                                <ControlStyle CssClass="link" />
                            </asp:HyperLinkField>

                            <asp:CommandField CausesValidation="false" ButtonType="Image" EditImageUrl="~/Icon/silk/application_edit.gif"
                                ShowEditButton="True" CancelImageUrl="~/Icon/silk/arrow_undo.gif" UpdateImageUrl="~/Icon/silk/accept.gif"
                                EditText="Edit" HeaderText="Edit" />

                        </Columns>
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#e8edf2" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="White"
                            Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Overline="False" Font-Size="X-Small"
                            Font-Underline="False" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#68a2d7" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

and in my code page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = Search_groups();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = Search_groups();
        if (GridViewSortExpresion != null && GridViewSortExpresion != "")
            SortGridView(GridViewSortExpresion, GridViewSortDirection);
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = Search_groups();
        if (GridViewSortExpresion != null && GridViewSortExpresion != "")
            SortGridView(GridViewSortExpresion, GridViewSortDirection);
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        using (_Category nc = new _Category())
        {
            if (Request["lang"] == "" || Request["lang"] == null)
                nc.Language = "fa";
            else
                nc.Language = Request["lang"];
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2 = Search_groups();
            int ncid = (int)dt2.Rows[e.RowIndex]["chid"];
            ncid = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text);
            nc.ID = ncid;
            nc.Name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
            nc.Updatefast();

            GridView1.DataSource = Search_groups();
            if (GridViewSortExpresion != null && GridViewSortExpresion != "")
                SortGridView(GridViewSortExpresion, GridViewSortDirection);
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            dt2.Dispose();
            gvr.Dispose();
        }
    }

    protected void Ibtnsearch_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = Search_groups();
        if (GridViewSortExpresion != null && GridViewSortExpresion != "")
            SortGridView(GridViewSortExpresion, GridViewSortDirection);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private DataTable Search_groups()
    {
        if (Request["nParentid_fk"] != null)
            parent_fk = Convert.ToInt32(Request["nParentid_fk"]);
        else
            parent_fk = 0;
        using (_Category nc = new _Category())
        {
            if (Request["lang"] == "" || Request["lang"] == null)
                nc.Language = "fa";
            else
                nc.Language = Request["lang"];
            if (txtname.Text != "")
                return nc.search_allcategories(txtname.Text);
            else
                return nc.Select_parentid_fk(parent_fk);

        }
    }

    public string GridViewSortDirection
    {
        get
        {
            //if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            //    ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;

            //return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
            if (SortDirection.Value == null)
                SortDirection.Value = "asc";

            return SortDirection.Value;
        }
        set { SortDirection.Value = value; }
    }

    public string GridViewSortExpresion
    {
        get
        {
            //if (ViewState["SortExpresion"] == null)
            //    ViewState["SortExpresion"] = "";
            //if (ViewState["SortExpresion"] != null)
            //    return ViewState["SortExpresion"].ToString();
            //else
            //    return null;
            if (SortExpresion.Value != null)
                return SortExpresion.Value.ToString();
            else
                return null;
        }
        set { SortExpresion.Value = value; }
    }

    protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        //DataTable dataTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

        GridViewSortExpresion = e.SortExpression;
        if (GridViewSortDirection == "asc")
        {

            GridViewSortDirection = "desc";
            SortGridView(GridViewSortExpresion, GridViewSortDirection);
        }
        else
        {

            GridViewSortDirection = "asc";
            SortGridView(GridViewSortExpresion, GridViewSortDirection);
        }
    }

    private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
    {
        //  You can cache the DataTable for improving performance
        //DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
        DataTable dt = Search_groups();
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.Sort = sortExpression + " " + direction;

        GridView1.DataSource = dv;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

when I try to update ,I get this error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

**Edit 2**

Now I found that my problem is that gridview loses datasource on post back ,
I search but I not found solution.I don't want to use session or viewstate,because I have a lot of tables like above ,What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

**set following property:**

set `AutoGenerateEditButton="False"`

Try putting:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button id="btnEdit" runat="server" commandname="Edit" text="Edit" />
            <asp:Button id="btnDelete" runat="server" commandname="Delete" text="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button id="btnUpdate" runat="server" commandname="Update" text="Update" />
            <asp:Button id="btnCancel" runat="server" commandname="Cancel" text="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In place of :

```
<asp:CommandField CausesValidation="false" ButtonType="Image" EditImageUrl="~/Icon/silk/application_edit.gif"
                                ShowEditButton="True" CancelImageUrl="~/Icon/silk/arrow_undo.gif" UpdateImageUrl="~/Icon/silk/accept.gif"
                                EditText="Edit" HeaderText="Edit" />
```

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S. com'on tuches. Mulgi disli re disli ki lagech answer

Comment: @Nitinvarpe kay bhau tumhi pan :)

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S. ;) khar e te khare, pan e tila marathi yet nasel na? Vichar bar tila

Comment: @Nitinvarpe hila marathi samajat aasel tar waat lagayachi aapali

Comment: @Nitinvarpe chyayala tumachya comment la upvote kela koni tari :D

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S. mala watal tumhich kelay hahahah te pan 2

Comment: 2 madhala ek mazz aahe..but dusara??

Comment: Kon ahe re tikde samor ya jara

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S. thank you, I want to try this,but how fire GridView1_RowEditing when I click on Edit?

Comment: @minamorsali RowEditing is fired when you give command as "Edit" to link/image button , updating event is fired when "Update" command given as i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S. I try this but RowEditing event not fire :(

Comment: @minamorsali ohh..have u kept debugger properly?

Comment: @minamorsali plz keep debugging point at rowediting function and page load, by this way you will come to know actually event is getting fired or not... (do you understand marathi language?)

Comment: oh yes I understand, yes I debug,Page load only fire but RowEditing or RowCommand events not fire.

Comment: @minamorsali tu use karat aahes grid binding sathi ti method actually correct aahe but ti good programming practice nahi...itemtemplate aani edittemplate use kar mhanaje tuza problem solve hoil :) (glad to know that u r marathi)

Comment: Oh no,I mean that I understand that what I must do,sorry I not understand marathi :)

Comment: @minamorsali ohh...the method which u have used to bind grid is correct but is not good programming practice.. try to use itemtemplates and edititemtemplates that will solve your problem. :)

Comment: @minamorsali this is happening because you are not again rebinding the grid